# Kotlin coroutines, how to async alist of calls and return the result as a map

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
var responseMap = mutableMapOf<VendorType, ChargeResponse>()
  requests.forEach {
    val response = when (it.vendorType) {
        VendorType.Type1 -> service.chargeForType1()
        VendorType.Type2 -> service.chargeForType2()

      else -> {
        throw NotImplementedError("${it.vendorType} does not support yet")
      }
    }
    responseMap[it.vendorType] = response
  }
  responseMap
```

So I want all the `service.charge` function run in separate thread. Return the map when all is done

Comment: Is `service.charge` a long calculation, or is it fetching something from a network?

Comment: it calls out to other service to charge users money. 2-3 seconds each

Comment: Usually, functions like that are either Kotlin `suspend` functions, or they take a callback. Is there a library you're working with?

Comment: Was using @Async with completableFuture. But still dont know how to use CompletableFuture in this situation.

Comment: Are you using a Java library or why do you have a completable future? If you are in controll of the code providing the future and its also kotlin, It might be helpful to instead use kotlin coroutines

Comment: I initially used have lib for this. But I changed to coroutines

Answer (score 3):

Hope to solve your problem:

Assume your service and request like this:

```kotlin
interface Service {
  suspend fun chargeForType1(): ChargeResponse
  suspend fun chargeForType2(): ChargeResponse
}

data class Request(val vendorType: VendorType)
```

```kotlin
suspend fun requestAll(requests: List<Request>): Map<VendorType, ChargeResponse> {
  return coroutineScope {
    requests
        .map { request ->
          async {
            request.vendorType to when (request.vendorType) {
              VendorType.Type1 -> service.chargeForType1()
              VendorType.Type2 -> service.chargeForType2()
              else -> throw NotImplementedError("${request.vendorType} does not support yet")
            }
          }
        }
        .awaitAll()
        .toMap()
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this out

Comment: Thanks you it seems to work. However, the `requestAll` is called by other function and I got `Suspend function 'requestAll' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

Comment: You can use CoroutineScope.launch { ... } to call it