# Processing and aggregating data from multiple servers efficiently

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, backend, sequence, coroutine

### Summary

My goal is to process and aggregate data from multiple servers efficiently while handling possible errors. For that, I
have a sequential version that I want to speed up. As I am using Kotlin, coroutines seem the way to go for this
asynchronous task. However, I'm quite new to this, and can't figure out how to do this idiomatic. None of my attempts
satisfied my requirements completely.

Here is the sequential version of the core function that I am currently using:

```kotlin
suspend fun readDataFromServers(): Set<String> = coroutineScope {
    listOfServers
        // step 1: read data from servers while logging errors
        .mapNotNull { url ->
            runCatching { makeRequestTo(url) }
                .onFailure { println("err while accessing $url: $it") }
                .getOrNull()
        }
        // step 2: do some element-wise post-processing    
        .map { process(it) }
        // step 3: aggregate data    
        .toSet()
}
```

### Background

In my use case, there are `numServers` I want to read data from. Each of them usually answers within `successDuration`,
but the connection attempt may fail after `timeoutDuration` with probability `failProb` and throw an `IOException`. As
downtimes are a common thing in my system, I do not need to retry anything, but only log it for the record. Hence,
the `makeRequestTo` function can be modelled as follows:

```kotlin
suspend fun makeRequestTo(url: String) =
    if (random.nextFloat() > failProb) {
        delay(successDuration)
        "{Some response from $url}"
    } else {
        delay(timeoutDuration)
        throw IOException("Connection to $url timed out")
    }
```

### Attempts

All these attempts can be tried out in the [Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/dW5B4MdPZ). I don't know how long this link stays alive; maybe I'll need to upload this as a gist, but I liked that people can execute the code directly.

#### Async

I tried using `async {makeRequestTo(it)}` after `listOfServers` and awaiting the results in the following `mapNotNull`
similar
to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475989/kotlin-coroutines-how-to-async-alist-of-calls-and-return-the-result-as-a-map)
. While this collapses the communication time to `timeoutDuration`, all following processing steps have to wait for that
long before they can continue. Hence, some composition of `Deferred`s was required here, which is discouraged in
Kotlin (or at least [should be avoided](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/342) in favor of suspending
functions).

```kotlin
suspend fun readDataFromServersAsync(): Set<String> = supervisorScope {
    listOfServers
        .map { async { makeRequestTo(it) } }
        .mapNotNull { kotlin.runCatching { it.await() }.onFailure { println("err: $it") }.getOrNull() }
        .map { process(it) }
        .toSet()
}
```

#### Loops

Using normal loops like below fulfills the functional requirements, but feels a bit more complex than it should be.
Especially the part where shared state must be synchronized makes me to not trust this code and any future modifications
to it.

```kotlin
val results = mutableSetOf<String>()
val mutex = Mutex()
val logger = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception -> println("err: $exception") }
for (server in listOfServers) {
    launch(logger) {
        val response = makeRequestTo(server)
        val processed = process(response)
        mutex.withLock {
            results.add(processed)
        }
    }
}
return@supervisorScope results
```